# Wildfly 10 deployment not working very well by replacing war file

Tags: java, wildfly

I have a java web application that is in charge to execute:

```
log.info("Welcome New York")
```

Then I build the war file and it's deployed to Wildfly 10. After that, I check it out the log file and I saw 'Welcome New York'. It's working so far.

Then I changed log.info("Welcome California") instead of log.info("Welcome New York"). I built the war file again and I redeployed to Wildfly through 'Replace' option. After that, I checked the log file and I saw 'Welcome New York' again instead of 'Welcome California'. So what I did is executing systemctl restart wildfly and it worked with the correct message.

Why didn't the 'Replace' option work?..   What was happening about Wildfly for this case?

Comment: What do you mean :" I redeployed to Wildfly through 'Replace' option. " as there are so many ways to deploy or redeploy an application

Comment: I mean: Wildfly Admin Console->Deployments->Select the app->Select Replace option->Select the war file and finish